# Sorting an array of integers in time complexity of o(n) or o(1)

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

What is the best algorithm that could sort an array of integers from 1 to 4 (very simple), in a time complexity of o(n) or less?

Comment: Time complexity is not measured that way..

Comment: Looks like a variant of the [Dutch National Flag problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem).

Comment: Are the values limited to 1 to 4 and the array of any size? If so use [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort). If it's an array of 4 values, use 6 if / swap statements as in a [sorting network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Radix Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort), which is O(n)

```
 public void radixsort(int[] input) {
  final int RADIX = 10;
  // declare and initialize bucket[]
  List<Integer>[] bucket = new ArrayList[RADIX];
  for (int i = 0; i < bucket.length; i++) {
    bucket[i] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  }

  // sort
  boolean maxLength = false;
  int tmp = -1, placement = 1;
  while (!maxLength) {
    maxLength = true;
    // split input between lists
    for (Integer i : input) {
      tmp = i / placement;
      bucket[tmp % RADIX].add(i);
      if (maxLength && tmp > 0) {
        maxLength = false;
      }
    }
    // empty lists into input array
    int a = 0;
    for (int b = 0; b < RADIX; b++) {
      for (Integer i : bucket[b]) {
        input[a++] = i;
      }
      bucket[b].clear();
    }
    // move to next digit
    placement *= RADIX;
  }
}
```

`code` [Ref](http://www.geekviewpoint.com/java/sorting/radixsort)

Comment: Rather than base 10 radix, it would be faster to use base 256 (one byte), which would only need 4 passes on 32 bit integers.